# BeautifulSoup, how can I stop my list of web link from overwrite each other?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, text-mining

the code below only give me the last word in the list

```
import csv
wo = csv.reader(open('WORD.csv') )
row=list(wo)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup  # HTML data structure
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq  # Web client

# URl to web scrape from.
# in this example we web scrape lexico 
with open("WORD.csv") as f:

    for row in csv.reader(f):
    
        for word in row:
      
        # Number of pages plus one
            url = "https://www.lexico.pt/{}".format(word)
            
# opens the connection and downloads html page from url
uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()


# parses html into a soup data structure to traverse html
# as if it were a json data type.
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# finds each product from the store page
containers = page_soup.find("div", {"class": "card card-pl card-pl-significado"})

# name the output file to write to local disk
out_filename = "test.csv"



# opens file, and writes headers
f = open(out_filename, "w")




Word = containers.h2.text

Defention = containers.p.text


f.write("\n" + Word + ", " + Defention + "\n")


f.close()
```

Please help I tried everything. I am a beginner to BeautifulSoup so sorry for my terrible code format

Comment: What is in Word.csv?

Comment: What's with the lorem ipsum?

Comment: I think you almost made it. You should revise your indentation and structure.

Comment: Can you share some more details on what your trying to scrape and some of the URLs your using. This way we can also see if there are other options to help you out.

Comment: mike67 - Word.csv is a list of word i text mine for the sentence.

Justin Ezequiel - pasting error 

@Ares Zephyr I am trying to scrape words I text mine from a book for I can create my own person dictionary.

https://www.lexico.pt/bom/
https://www.lexico.pt/legal/
https://www.lexico.pt/venda/

Comment: @JustinEzequiel the site doesn't allow new users to post questions that are mostly code. The intention is to get them to describe their problem better and add more relevant details. Unfortunately, some people choose to get around the restriction by adding garbage to pad their question.

Comment: @AlexJean, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and [ask], and condense your code down to a [mre]. 
 You will also find this useful: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned earlier, I believe that you have already achieved your goal.

In python, the scope is determined by indenting. This defines the area of validity of the local variables. Since you do not follow this continuously in your example, the iteration is already complete when your first request is sent. The loop variable has already been reassigned and contains the result of the last iteration step.

```
# open files for reading and writing
with open('WORD.csv') as src, open('test.txt', 'w') as dst:
    # read row by row
    for row in csv.reader(src):
        # get words separated by comma
        for word in row:
            # open connection and create parser with read data
            url = f'https://www.lexico.pt/{word}'
            resp = urlopen(url)
            html = soup(resp.read(), 'html.parser')
            # find card/content
            card = html.find('div', {'class':'card-pl-significado'})
            word = card.h2.text
            desc = card.p.text
            # write formatted result to file
            dst.write(f'{word}, {desc}\n')
```

Have fun

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_ _Especially when OP is a beginner who's asking because they don't know why their code doesn't work._ ["Give a man a fish ..."](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)